# Decrease windows 7 system boot up?

Tags: windows-7, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Very long boot up process?](https://superuser.com/questions/243800/very-long-boot-up-process)

As you can see the system takes up 3/4 of my bootup time and i cant really uninstall anything from there. I tried using the history to track it down but it goes up and down too randomly. I suspect it has something to do with system updates but really, how can it add 30 more seconds back when i first complained at 1m25sec.

Is there anything i can do to decrease this? I'm going to do system updates right now and see what happens.

[image]

Comment: Honestly, why are you worried about 1:57, it's windows, It takes time, If your computer were to take up longer then 5 minutes I'd be happy to help you since then there actually would be something wrong!

Comment: See my answer here...http://superuser.com/questions/243800/very-long-boot-up-process

Comment: Also see this article, works for W7 also...http://www.zdnet.com/blog/bott/microsofts-hidden-diagnostic-tool-unlocks-vista-startup-secrets/246

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that a lot of that is stuff initializing and going into memory from the disk, upgrading to a solid state drive is the single biggest thing you can do.  (This is a big assumption without knowing specifics of what your hardware and software is though.)